# ASP.NET MVC and AngularJS routing not working

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am working on ASP.NET MVC site with AngularJS 1.7.5
So I have been created simple MVC project and added angularJS to the  solution.
Than I have created routing.js file:

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ["MyApp.controllers","ngRoute"])
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $localProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("#!/", {
                redirectTo: function () {
                    return "/home";
                }
            })
            .when("/", {
                templateUrl: "/home/index",
                controller: "HomeController"
            })
            .when("/contact", {
                templateUrl: "/Home/Contact",
                controller: "ContactController"
            })
            .when("/About/:id", {
                templateUrl: "/Home/About",
                controller: "BlogController"
            })
            .otherwise({
                templateUrl: "Home/Index",
                controller: "HomeController"
            })

        //$localProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix("!");
        $localProvider.hashPrefix("");
    })
```

and I want to call *.cshtml files from `Views` folder, but it seams not working now...

in index file i have 4 links

Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/JSControllers/MyApp.js"></script>
}

<a href="#/">Home</a>
<a href="#/">Home2</a>
<a href="#/contact">Contact</a>
<a href="#/About/2">Blog id 2</a>

<div ng-view></div>
```

So can any one point me of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should be using `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');`, which removes `!` from the hash-bang, so remove it from links: `<a href="#/">Home</a>`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey this didn't help also =(

Comment: MVC is a view and model framework (server-side), Angular is a view and model framework (client-side) - and is really designed to work with everthing within a single HTML document (as opposed to MVC which generates lots of separate HTML documents as its views). Putting them together strikes me as a bit of a muddled design choice, TBH. Angular + Web API would make a lot more sense as an architecture.